# Copy filefield image to different filefield field

Tags: rules, views

I am upgrading an older D6 site to D7. Way back we made the mistake of creating separate image fields for different content types. So instead of just creating a field field-image and reusing it, we have a field-event-image, a field-testimonial-image and so on (and a field-image). Well, besides the excess clutter, we need to create a view that shows a flexslide that sources nodes from multiple content types and it only allows one image field. So I would like to move all the images into the field-image field. I have seen a number of potential ways to achieve this result but no luck so far. Using migrate module is probably the most elegant, but seems over my head. VBO with Rules seems good and I have seen some examples but I get stuck creating the rule.

Any suggestions to my dilemma? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by running SQL on the database directly through phpmyadmin.
First I added the destination field to the content type.
Then, I went into phpmyadmin and ran this: (change your field names as appropriate.

```
INSERT field_data_field_image SELECT * FROM field_data_field_event_image;
```

and

```
INSERT field_revision_field_image SELECT * FROM field_revision_field_event_image;
```

After it ran successfully, I went in and checked the content. All good. Then I was able to delete the old field. Problem solved! Thanks.

Comment: Be careful here. If the file was used only on one field - Deleting the field would cause deleting the image as well. This is because with your db update you would not update the file_usage table.

Comment: Good bit of information. This issue is far behind me now. I might have run into this but I would have just restored the file from the backup if it was missing...